# Jira integration not showing labels in drop down

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I have a have a cloud version of artifactory and am trying to get a jira integration setup. I have successfully authenticated to jira and am able to list the projects inside my jira account, however the labels are not showing up from the drop down. The only labels showing up are the jfrog defined ones. I went and looked through the developer console and figured out the URL that it should be hitting which in this case:

```
https://REDACTED/ui/api/v1/xray/ui/ticketing/integrations/labels/list?integrationName=jira
```

And the list of labels returned so I know it is not a permission problem. I am at a loss at this point as this url never seems to be hit when I go to setup the XRAY scan profile and can not list labels.

I should also point out the authentication is through Oauth 1.0

Giving my ROLE Admin permissions all the way
Calling the labels list command manually
Recreating the integration multiple times